# How to call java method from jruby

Tags: eclipse, jruby

I am learing Jruby and i have following code in my eclipse

```
public class Test {
  public Test()
  {
      System.out.print("object created");
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {}
}
```

Now i am exporting this project as `runnable jar`. since `runnable jar` looks for main method, So i have created main method.

Now i can create object of `Test Class` in jruby like this

```
require 'java'
require 'test.jar'

foo = Test.new
```

and it is giving me the output `object created`

Now i want to export it as `jar` instead of `runnable jar`. So for exporting project as `jar` `main method` is not required.

So my java code looks like this

```
public class Test {
  public Test()
  {
    System.out.print("object created");
  }
}
```

Then i am again creating object of `Test Class` same as above

```
require 'java'
require 'test.jar'

foo = Test.new
```

Now it is giving me the error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Test
  const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:3309
          <top> at test.rb:4
```

Since i am new to jruby, i don't know why exporting as `runnable jar` works but exporting as `jar` doesn't works.

And which one is the best way, to export as `runnable jar` or to export as `jar`.

Please explain in detail since i am new to jruby and there are not much documentation provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class. You have included Jar package but did not import class itself. Import it like this `java_import "Test"`